# How to add Sidebar and Full width option in post editor

Tags: sidebar, theme-options, post-editor

If a user is editing a page, they have the option to choose any page template for that page through the edit screen. Wordpress does not have that option for posts.

I installed the Sparkling theme and noticed that they were able to include layout options for the user to select on the posts edit screen.

How would I be able to do the same thing on my theme? Perhaps someone can guide me in the right direction.

I included a screen shot and circled the options I am trying to add to my theme:

[image]

Comment: You can do this using  metaboxes checkout https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

Comment: Tutorial for that https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this, I personally prefer the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. You'll need to grab the fields and deal with them on the front end too.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress provides a template hierarchy which gives you the flexibility to create custom layouts for posts, pages, archives, etc. To create a custom layout for a specific blog post, you would name the template single-{post-type}-{slug}.php

You can find out more about the template hierarchy [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Comment: I thought this feature is only available for page templates? So you mean I can create a new template named single-post-fullwidth.php and it will show up in the posts edit screen?

Comment: yes of course the example which you mentioned above done same thing

Comment: Here's what I did: I created two templates files and named them single-post-fullwidth.php and single-post-sidebar.php and I also included a php statement in each file to give them each a unique name. <?php Post template name: fullwidth ?> I read about this somewhere else and it seems like that this method requires a plugin but I am trying to accomplish this without the use of a plugin

Comment: <?php
/*
Template Name: Template_Name
*/
?>  give your template name and select it than you can accomplish your goal

Comment: <?php /* Template Name: Template_Name */ ?> this statement only applies to pages though I am referring to the post type Posts

Comment: Yes of course you can make template like "Full Width", "Right Sidebar","Left Sidebar" and so on. Select option Page Template from right hand site.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a [custom metabox](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/). You can then use the selected value to choose your template part.

eg. if fullwidth is chosen:- get_template_part('template-part/','fullwidth'); where 'template-part/' is a folder and 'fullwidth' is file with .php extension. [read more here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/)

There are a lot of online generators to create a metabox if you want to skip the hassle of making one your self. Simply generate and paste the code in functions.php of your theme

check out https://jeremyhixon.com/tool/wordpress-meta-box-generator/

Answer (score -1):

This option is likely added with `post_meta`. The panel option looks like it was was added with the `add_meta_box`.

[Post meta is a common place to put additional data to posts in WordPress.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_meta_Function_Examples)

[Post meta boxes are an easy way to show fields for this options to be displayed](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/).